# Unix sort text file with user-defined newline character

Tags: unix, sorting, character, newline, user-defined

I have a plain text file where newline character in not `"\n"` but a special character.

Now I want to sort this file.

Is there a direct way to specify custom new-line character while using unix `sort` command?
I don't want to use a script for this as far as possible?

Please note the data in text file have `\n`, `\r\n`, and `\t` characters(the reason for such data is application specific so please don't comment on that).

The sample data is as below:

```
1111\n1111<Ctrl+A>
2222\t2222<Ctrl+A>
3333333<Ctrl+A>
```

Here `Ctrl+A` is the newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `perl -001e 'print sort <>'` to do this:

```
prompt$ cat -tv /tmp/a
2222^I2222^A3333333^A1111
1111^A

prompt$ perl -001e 'print sort <>' /tmp/a | cat -tv    
1111
1111^A2222^I2222^A3333333^Aprompt$
```

That works because character 001 (octal 1) is control-A (`"\cA"`), which is your record terminator in this dataset.

You can also use the code point in hex using `-0xHHHHH`.  Note that it must be a single code point, not a string, using this shortcut.  There are ways of doing it for strings and even regexes that involve infinitessimally more code.